# Summation of only numbers in spreadtab package

Tags: spreadtab

I recently discovered the `spreadtab` package since I needed some spreadsheets with some calculations.

I would like to produce a LaTeX file with the grades of my students, i. e. something like this (eight problems 10 points each and the total sum). However, I also would like to put dash `-` instead of zero if the student didn't write anything for this problem. But then the usual `sum` is not working. Is it possible to adjust this?

Here is a standard code (without dashes). Ideally, modified `sum` should simply avoid cells with `-`, so some sort of conditional summation should work.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{spreadtab}

\begin{document}

\begin{spreadtab}{{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}}
\hline
@ 1 & @ 2 & @ 3 & @ 4 & @ 5 & @ 6 & @ 7 & @ 8 & @ $\sum$  \\
\hline
10 & 10 & 10 & 10 & 10 & 10 & 10 & 10 & sum(a2:h2) \\
\hline
\end{spreadtab}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert a `@` before the  dash.

[image: aa]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{spreadtab}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{spreadtab}{{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}}
        \hline
        @ 1 & @ 2   & @ 3   & @ 4   & @ 5   & @ 6   & @ 7   & @ 8   & @ $\sum$  \\
        \hline
        10  & 10    & 10    & @ -   & 10    & 10    & 10    & 10    & sum(a2:h2) \\
        \hline
    \end{spreadtab}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, Simon, that works!